Google sheet formula for combining a text and an extracted date with days added
I am trying to extract a date from a text, then add ten days to the date and combine it with a new text.
In cell A1 I have the text:
First date is 2024-01-01
In a new cell I try to get the text:
New date is 2024-01-11
I tried:
=TO_DATE(RIGHT(A1,10)+10)
This works fine and gives me ”2024-01-11”
I tried:
="Same date is "&TO_DATE(RIGHT(A1,10))
This also works fine and gives me ”Same date is 2024-01-01”.
Then I tried the combination expecting ”New date is 2024-01-11”:
="New date is "&TO_DATE(RIGHT(A1,10)+10)
But I end up with ”New date is 45302”.
Why and how do I get it right?


You may try:
="New date is "&text(right(A1,10)+10,"yyy-mm-dd")


RIGHT is not very versatile. to target date in any text, try:
="New date is "&TEXT(REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}")+10, "e-mm-dd")



